# Error El servidor MySQL no autorizó su acceso

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo el siguiente error, y ya he hecho de todo y no cambia nada

[image: Errores]

Tengo el puerto configurado para que sea el 3307 en todos los lugares posibles, tengo **config.inc** configurado de la siguiente manera:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '*****';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:3007';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';
```

le cambio el cookie a config y sigue con el error, en esta parte

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:3007';
```

lo he cambiado varias veces por la ip http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin, http://127.0.0.1/3307, solo la ip, de todas las maneras posibles

En el xampp no hay errores
[image: Aqui no hay errores]

No se que más hacer o si es un problema externo, aunque por todas las veces que busqué, no parece. Si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: Si estás usando el puerto 3307 ¿ está bien que en la config de phpmyadmin diga localhost:3**0**07?

Comment: @aeportugal es verdad, mi error entonces, ahora me sale un error completamente diferente, mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 
pero muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás apuntando incorrectamente al puerto por lo que veo. Si dices que este lo has configurado en el 3307, en lugar de:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:3007';
```

Debería ser:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:3307';
```

ó

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3307';
```

Comment: es verdad, fue mi error, ahora me sale un problema diferente pero al menos ese ya esta solucionado, gracias
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: @Wiska Tienes algún dato incorrecto en tu inicio de sesión. A veces pasa, porque en tu contraseña tienes caracteres especiales y no las reconoce, intenta ponerle una clave plana como 12345 para que hagas la prueba. Si no, deja la contraseña en blanco 
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';` y sólo autentifícate con root en el usuario

Comment: @Wiska + aunque veo que tienes activado el `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;`, por lo que no necesitas una contraseña en el formulario, con que pongas root en el usuario y la contraseña vacía podrás acceder